# Jest test fails SyntaxError, unexpected token Export

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

I have a test failing with the error `Unexpected token 'export'` due to code imported from `swiper` package, I added node_modules to transformIgnorePatterns in my config but that is not working. Configs below:

```
"jest": {
    "watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules",
        ".jest-test-results.json"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
         "\\.(css)$": "<rootDir>/test/jest/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
         "<rootDir>/node_modules/swiper/core/core.js": "<rootDir>/test/jest/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that I wasn't specifying packages in trasnformIgnorePatterns. Following works:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/(?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7))"
        ],
```